# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Network 'default' does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I try to use the endpoints follow this document: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine 
On the step 'Deploying the API backend',
when I try to run 'gcloud app deploy target/appengine-staging',met this issue: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Network 'default' does not exist
What's the wrong on the step? Where can I manage the network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify otherwise, the deployment tries to use the "default" network in your project. You may have deleted that network previously. You can either recreate the default network on your project or set a different network in your app.yaml file like so:

```
network:
  instance_tag: TAG_NAME
  name: NETWORK_NAME
  subnetwork_name: SUBNETWORK_NAME
```

You can find more details about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#network_settings).

Comment: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Network 'xxx-qa' does not have a subnetwork named 'test-asia-east2' in region 'us-central1'. 'test-asia-east2' in the region 'asia-east2'. So how to adjust the yaml file?

Comment: you can only deploy to a network/subnetwork that is in the same region that the one you chose for your App Engine app at creation time. In which region is your GAE app located?

Comment: I don't know, maybe us-central. Looks like i need delete the GAE and recreate it.